# How to choose SSD persistant disk on Google Container engine?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Just checked, while creating the container cluster, we are not able to find option to set SSD persistant disk on Google cloud container engine. How do I set that. Note we are using paid plans on GCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to choose the type of boot disk that is attached to each node, but you can mount SSD PDs into your containers using [volumes](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/volumes.html).